# Volume icon disappeared without any apparent reason

Tags: indicator, volume-control, indicator-sound

[image]

The icon used to be around there. Now gone.
Any idea how I can restore it?

Ubuntu 18.10

Sound is working perfectly fine though and I can change the volume in the settings.
But no icon.